# Creating a survey using Coldfusion: Stuck on the table data insert

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I'm trying to create a survey tool in Coldfusion and I'm stuck on one part.

My tables are:

- `t_forms` (id, name, desc)
- `t_questions` (id, question, type, formid, order)
- `t_cdata` (id, email)
- `t_cqdata` (formid, questionid, customerid, answergiven)

The form fields are dynamically built using a url variable and look like this, for example:

```
<cfquery name="gs">
    select * from t_forms where id = #url.sid#
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="gq">
       select * from t_questions where fid = #gs.id# ORDER BY order ASC
</cfquery>

<cfform name="survey" method="post" action="">
    <cfloop query="gq">
       <cfinput type="text" name="q#gq.id#">
    </cfloop>
    <cfinput type="text" name="email">
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="fid" value="#url.fid#">
    <cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</cfform>
```

However, I'm having trouble when I need to put the value of the answer into the `t_cqdata` table, as the form element input needs to go into the table as well.

If anyone could help or point out where I am going wrong, that would be appreciated .

Comment: _I'm having trouble when I need to put the value of the answer into the t_cqdata table_ If your problem is with the inserting of data into the table then you need to include the code that is attempting to do that. We can't really help much with the lack of info you have provided thus far. Update your question with more details and the code that is not working for you.

Comment: So on the processing page, the form variable dump looks like:
     `struct
    'FIELDNAMES Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,SUBMIT'
     Q1 1
     Q2 1
     Q3 1
     Q4 dsrbdsarb
     SUBMIT Send`

So what i need to be able to do is put this data into the t_cqdata table, how do I put the question id in along with the value?

Comment: I'm still not following you. Just use that form data in a sql insert statement to populate your database with the data.  You still have not included an example of what you are trying to do (I mean the code) so I don't know how to help you.

Comment: One item that might cause trouble is the use of url variables.  You are posting the form to the page containing the form, those varibles will no longer exist.  You are going to have to have some if/else logic to determine if you are creating the form or proessing it.

Comment: Like this [SQL INSERT INTO Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: I can add in SQL normally, however how do I link the questions id with the form element answer for that question?

Comment: Include the question id with your form. That way the question id is submitted with the form answers and you can use it in your code.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this.  My preference is to append it to the name of the formfield.

Comment: *how do I link the questions id with the form element answer for that question?* Exactly where are the answer fields in the form code? All I see is `<cfinput name="q#gq.id#">`.  Is the "q" supposed to mean that field contains a "question" id? (Hard to tell from the naming conventions.)  If so, where are the answer fields you mentioned?  We understand things may not be "working" correctly yet, but it is still helpful to post the non-working code. The field types, placement, etc... all convey relevant information about the problem.

Comment: As an aside, nothing to do with the issue, but there are a few improvements that could be made to the code a) Always use `cfqueryparam` user supplied query parameters to protect the database against sql injection and b) In this case, there is no need for multiple queries. Use a `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to have form fields associated with database identifier values.  This is the one I find easiest to comprehend.

On the form page.

```
<cfoutput query="somequery">
<input name="field1#databaseID#">
<input name="field2#databaseID#">
```

etc

On the processing page.

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="ThisElement">
<cfif left (ThisElement, 6) is "field1">
<cfset ThisID = RemoveChars(ThisElement, 1, 6)>
<cfset ThisField1Value = form[ThisElement]>
<cfset ThisField2Value = form['field2' & ThisID]>
```

Continue to set variables and then do something with them.  In fact, in this example, once you've set `ThisID`, setting more variables is optional.  You can simply use the form variables directly using the synax shown.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use an insert into cfquery.

You would use something like:

    INSERT INTO t_cqdata
        (q1
        ,q2
        ,q3
        ,q4
        ,q5
        ,q6
        ,q7)
    VALUES
        (
        ,
        ,
        ,
        ,
        ,)